# ScrollRect.onValueChanged how to change it using script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello guys I need help changing the value in ScrollRect.onValueChanged… don’t know how to change it using script… anyone does? Please I tried searching everywhere but can’t find answer…

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
    {
      void Start()
      {
        UIZoomImage zoomScript;
        zoomScript= GameObject.FindWithTag(“Original”).GetComponent<UIZoomImage>();
        ScrollRect scrollRect =GameObject.FindWithTag(“Control1”).GetComponent<ScrollRect>();
        scrollRect.onValueChanged.AddListener(zoomScript.OnPointerDown);
      }
    }
```

But gives me this error
`cannot convert from ‘method group’ to ‘UnityAction<Vector2>’`

I tried searching online but can’t get an straight answer… because if I can manually, why I can’t using Script?

I understood that i need to create a method that acts as a bridge between the event and the method I actually want to call, but have no idea.

Please.. anyone…

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! What you want is `unity3d` .. would make your question more visible to the correct people if you use the correct tags ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is asking, for me it worked using this line of code

```
private void Start () {
  // ...
  scrollRect.onValueChanged.AddListener (OnValueChanged);  // subscribe the bridge method to the event
}

private void OnValueChanged (Vector2 value) {  // bridge method fulfills the requirements of the event
  zoomScript.OnPointerDown ();  // call the desired method with default value
}
```

or use the short version:

```
private void Start () {
  // ...
  scrollRect.onValueChanged.AddListener ((value) => { zoomScript.OnPointerDown (); });
}
```